# Rsyslogs new configuration format for input files

Tags: linux, logging, rsyslog

I'm configuring a centralized logging with rsyslog.
I have to specify a input-file with some kind of WildCard but can't find any examples of how to get it working, in the description of the official documentation [here](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v7-stable/configuration/basic_structure.html#inputs) a link with an exact description seems broken.
I try to log tomcat7-logfiles that look like `localhost_access_log.2015-07-15.txt`.
The date in the file updates every day.

What I want to get is some kind of `input(type="imfile" ...)`

I tried it with:

```
input(type="imfile" tag="access_log" statefile="tomcat-access-log"
       file="/var/log/tomcat7/localhost_access_log.*.txt")
```

but this is not working and I don't get what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my full code:

```
$ModLoad imfile
$PrivDropToGroup adm
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

# catalina.log
$InputFileName /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.log
$InputFileTag catalina-log
$InputFileStateFile stat-catalina-log
$InputFileSeverity info
$InputRunFileMonitor

# localhost_access_log.YYYY.MM.DD.txt
input(type="imfile" tag="access_log" statefile="tomcat-access-log" file="/var/log/tomcat7/localhost_access_log.*.txt")
```

The catalina-logs are working as they are supposed to, however I'm not getting any access-logs in my output.

Any help would be appreciated, please remind me if I'm doing something completely wrong or if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will only work as of rsyslog v8.5 or newer (not 7) and only when using inotify see [here](http://www.slideshare.net/rainergerhards1/using-wildcards-with-rsyslogs-file-monitor-imfile) for a presentation explaing the requirements.
I forced inotify (although it is the default) with:

```
module(load="imfile"
     mode="inotify"
)
```

The input is defined like this:

```
input(type="imfile"
     File="/file/path/*.log"
     Tag="taskproject:"
     Facility="local3"
)
```

After this, it should be working